# Cypress.io: How to use one Login test for different user types?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, ui-automation, cypress

I'm using Cypress.io to test a third party page.

I want to test a login page and have different users. All Users have access to different content. So I have to check if they get the right page.  I want to use 1 Test and pass data to this test.

without variables I have this code:

```
cy.xpath("path)
.type('manager')
cy.xpath("path")
.type('password')
cy.xpath('path for login button')
.click()
```

How can I start doing this?  can I use fixtures for this? if yes, how? can I write my login with variables into the commands to use it in other tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will suggest iterating by `[key, value]` pairs, like:

```
describe('Login', () => {
    const userType = new Map([
        ['userX', password],
        ['userY', password],
        ['userZ', password],
    ]);
        for (const [key, value] of userType.entries()) {
            it(`should be logged as ${key}`, () => {
                cy.visit('/login');
                cy.xpath("path).type(key)
                cy.xpath("path").type(value)
                cy.xpath('path_for_login_button').click()
                /* 

                    assert logic here

                 */

                cy.visit('/logout')
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi thank you, but where can i define the keys? and users?

Comment: I tried this and it works for me. but when I use "if - else" in the logic 

like 

`if (key == 'Manager') {
   cy.xpath('path')
   .should('contain', 'Manager')
   }
   
   if(key == 'Developer')
   {
    cy.xpath('path')
   .should('contain', 'Developer')
   }` 

i get an error message (Timed Out) for manager. and for developer it does not check the if case.

Comment: I think you don't need an if/else statement here. In case the object you try to assert over contains the user type, Manager or Developer, simply do:
`cy.xpath('path').should('contain', key)`